# to Download the selected file?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
 public FileDownloadController() {          
    InputStream stream = ((ServletContext)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getResourceAsStream("/images/optimusprime.jpg");  
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "downloaded_optimus.jpg");  
}
```

In this above code we can download only jpg file. i want to download any format of file selected in UI is there any option?

Comment: Unformatted code, broken English with an incomprehensible question, `????` used, etc...

Comment: @H2CO3 oh come on, I was able to edit it into something comprehensible with little-to-no effort.

Comment: @MattBall Maybe you got the idea because you're a native English speaker. I honestly had no idea what OP was talking about.

Comment: Arun, ajax4jsf is a sublibrary of RichFaces. But you're using PrimeFaces. Please do not use the `[ajax4jsf]` tag then. If you have a question specifically related to using ajax in JSF, just add the `[ajax]` tag.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a MIME type other than `"image/jpg"` to the `DefaultStreamedContent` constructor. Specifically, pass the MIME type of whatever it is that you're trying to download, or [don't pass a MIME type at all](http://dzeek.homelinux.com/javadoc/primefacesdocs/org/primefaces/model/DefaultStreamedContent.html#DefaultStreamedContent%28java.io.InputStream%29).